# unit testing explicit cast error on interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface

I have an issue with a unit test failing due to an explicit cast error for an interface.

I am not sure if there is a solution for this, but I haven't found one clear enough yet for my particular scenario.

In my constructor I pass the interface of the data model `IAssetDataModel theAssetDataModel`. Then later on I explicitly cast that `Idatamodel` to my specific implementation. This fails to execute at runtime in my unit test.

```java
public EventFinder(IEventFinder Successor,
                       IAssetDataModel theAssetDataModel,
                       IAssetEventHandler theEventHandler)
    : base(Successor, theAssetDataModel, theEventHandler) {}

    // later on I make this cast to call the method I need
    List stuff = ((IMyOtherDataModel)_AssetDataModel).GetListOfStuff();
```

Here is where it fails in my unit test... I have a stub of this method, but it fails the explicit cast at runtime and I am unsure why.

I created a stub of this model in the unit test, but it still fails.

```kotlin
var stub_my_Data_model = new StubImyAssetDataModel();
stub_my_Data_model.Getstuff = () =>
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        results.Add("test1");
        return results;
    };
```

Comment: Well you're passing in something which presumably *isn't* an `IMyOtherDataModel`, so the cast fails. Why would you expect it to work? And more importantly, why is your constructor only taking `IAssetDataModel` if you're later assuming it has to be an `IMyOtherDataModel`?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I understand it seems weird, but I am still having trouble getting around it and I know there is a solution. The IAssetDataModel is the interface all other Data Models inherit from. This gives flexibility to the method calling it. I can't pass MyDataModel because of the inheritance of other methods. Again thank you for responding

Comment: You're not *really* giving flexibility to the caller. You're giving the illusion of flexibility. You're saying, "Sure, pass me any data model you want. That's fine. I'll just wait until later on before I fail if you haven't passed me the kind of data model I really need." Why do you accept values you won't actually be able to use?

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet! I appreciate your response I was able to find a solution. I know that this model in principle seems like it is an illusion, but I promise you it works like I described.

Comment: Except it clearly doesn't fulfil the promise of the signature, as otherwise you wouldn't have this error. I strongly advise you to reconsider your approach.

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate your desire to make sure things are done correctly and prevent me or anyone from making the wrong decision.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and the answer is to just create an implementation of the data Model in the test class that derives from the interface.

```
public class TestDataModel : IMyInterface{}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future people with this problem. I recently had this issue converting from `IEnumerable<IBlah>` to `IEnumerable<Blah>`. The way I got around it was to use a linq select statement and cast each one as I iterated through it. like so:

```
var interfaceValues = service.returnIBlahItems();
var castedValues = interfaceValues.Select(item => (Blah) item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're stubbing `Getstuff` rather than `GetListOfStuff` - perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: Please avoid asking questions in answers. They risk being flagged as "not-an-answer".